# Can't get selected value select with onSelectedChange

Tags: angular, typescript, html-select

I use angular version 9.
I want get selected value in select component with `(ngModelChange)`.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedLang" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedChange($event)">
        <option [value]="1">English</option>
        <option [value]="2">Turkish</option>
        <option [value]="3">Russian</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

COMPONENT

```
 selectedLang:any=1;
 
 onSelectedChange(value) { //not worked
    console.log(value);
}
```

I really surprised what is problem. I already tried `(change)` instead of `(ngModelChange)`.
Thanks.

Comment: seems fine here. could you run your app in aot mode, maybe it can reveal some statically detectable problems?

Comment: Maybe. What can you suggest to me?

Comment: `ng serve --aot` should serve your app in aot mode. check if it gives some errors

Comment: Your code works fine: https://angular-ivy-rw9gtk.stackblitz.io

Comment: I tried now. Have not any error. @Andrei

Comment: @RameshReddy because I need change trigger.

Comment: @Roy Do you can open link ?)